# Javascript Scope in Injected Function

Tags: javascript, scope

```
(function(){
    var privateSomething = "Boom!";
    var fn = function(){}
    fn.addFunc = function(obj) {
        alert('Yeah i can do this: '+privateSomething);
        for(var i in obj) fn[i] = obj[i];
    }
    window.fn=fn;
})();

fn.addFunc({
    whereAmI:function()
    {
        alert('Nope I\'ll get an error here: '+privateSomething);
    }
});

fn.whereAmI();
```

Why can't whereAmI() access privateSomething? and how do i place whereAmI() in the same context as addFunc()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is lexically scoped: a name refers to variables based on where the name is defined, not where the name is used. `privateSomething` is looked for as a local in `whereAmI`, and then in the global scope.  It isn't found in either of those places.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has lexical scoping, not dynamic scoping (apart from `this`). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_and_dynamic_scoping

Comment: `this` is a keyword not a variable. It has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: Gotcha. So no go on getting at that variable huh?

Comment: `this` is a reference to an object (or `undefined`), and it is resolved dynamically.

Comment: i think `this` is a keyword and everything to do with scope.